# How remove HTML5 form validation after cleaning contact form with JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a contact form, it has validation in javascript. I want to clear the form after the message is submited.

I clean it with

```
$(':input', '#contact')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :radio, :checkbox')
.val('');
```

After that the form is clean but HTML5 validation is trigered so I have inputs highlighted in red. How can I remove red color, please help.

(Added later)I don't know what to do, I have his code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/conexion/config.php',
data: $("#contact").serialize()+"&filename="+response.filename+"&filepath="+response.filepath,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
success: function(data) {
if(data == "true") {
$("#message").replaceWith('<div id="message"><p>El mensaje</p><p>ha sido enviado</p></div>');                                       $(':input', '#contact')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :radio, :checkbox')
.val('');
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
return false;
```

Comment: I edited my answer below, is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML5 validation still triggered, just add novalidate inside your form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate>...</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you alexoulu and Ricky Stam, I finally disabled HTML5 validation but not inside form tag. I disabled it in jquery by $('#contact').attr('novalidate',true); So if the browser has JS disable, it will validate with HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" onclick="submitForm()">

function submitForm() {
   // Get the first form with the name
   // Hopefully there is only one, but there are more, select the correct index
   var frm = document.getElementsByName('contact-form')[0];
   frm.submit(); // Submit
   frm.reset();  // Reset
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
```

Comment: Sorry for previous answer i misunderstood